# Evaluate: $\sum_{j=0}^{k}\sum_{i=0}^{j}{k \choose j}^2{k \choose i}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-theorem

**Can anybody help me to evaluate this sum $(1)$?**

$$\sum_{j=0}^{k}\sum_{i=0}^{j}{k \choose j}^2{k \choose i}\tag1$$

I have manage to figure out:

$$\sum_{j=0}^{k}\sum_{i=0}^{j}{k \choose j}{k \choose i}=\frac{4^k+{2k \choose k}}{2}\tag2$$
 and

$$\sum_{j=0}^{k}\sum_{i=0}^{j}{k+1 \choose j+1}^2{k \choose i}=2^k{2k \choose k}\frac{2k+1}{k+1}\tag3$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We start with
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^k}&\color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}{j}^2\binom{k}{i}}\\
> &=2^k\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}\binom{k}{k-j}\\
> &=2^k\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}[z^{k-j}](1+z)^k\tag{1}\\
> &=2^k[z^k](1+z)^k\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}z^j\tag{2}\\
> &=2^k[z^k](1+z)^{2k}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=2^k\binom{2k}{k}}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^p]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^p$.
- In (2) we apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$.
- In (3) we select the coefficient of $z^k$.

> We obtain from (3)
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j=0}^k&\sum_{i=0}^j\binom{k}{j}^2\binom{k}{i}=2^k\binom{2k}{k}-\sum_{j=0}^k\sum_{i=j+1}^k\binom{k}{j}^2\binom{k}{i}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
>
> The right-hand sum of (4) gives
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^k}&\color{blue}{\sum_{i=j+1}^k\binom{k}{j}^2\binom{k}{i}}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^k\sum_{i=k-j+1}^k\binom{k}{j}^2\binom{k}{i}\tag{5}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^k\sum_{i=-j+1}^0\binom{k}{j+k}^2\binom{k}{i}\tag{6}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^k\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}\binom{k}{k-j}^2\binom{k}{i}\tag{7}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^k\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}\binom{k}{j}^2\binom{k}{i}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{j=0}^k\sum_{i=0}^j\binom{k}{j}^2\binom{k}{i}-\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}^3}\tag{8}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (5) we change the order of the outer sum $j\to k-j$.
- In (6) we shift the index $i$ by $k$.
- In (7) we replace $i$ with $-i$.

> We conclude from (4) and (8)
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^k\sum_{i=0}^j\binom{k}{j}^2\binom{k}{i}=2^{k-1}\binom{2k}{k}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}^3}
> \end{align*}
>
> with $\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}^3$ the *[Franel numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FranelNumber.html)* stored as *[A000172](https://oeis.org/A000172)* in OEIS.

Comment: Interesting work. Verified. (+1).

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Many thanks for your friendly comment and the credit, Marko. :-)

Comment: An explanation to this answer is: let A be a matrix such that Aij = (kCi) * (kCj)^2, then the sum you want is the sum of lower triangular part of A = SL. Note that the sum of upper triangular part of A = SU is also equal to SL. Finally, we have SA=SU+SL-SD, where SA is the sum of all elements in A, and SD is the sum of Diagonal of A.

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful answer. I have check the link on Franel number, I am still curious, does this sum $\sum_{j=0}^{k}{k \choose j}^3$ have a closed form?

Comment: I manage to find a closed form for this sum (*similar to Franel*) $$\sum_{j=0}^{k}\left[{2k \choose 2j}^3-{2k \choose 2j-1}^3\right]=(-1)^k{2k \choose k}{3k \choose k}$$

Comment: @coffee: You're welcome. Since there is no closed formula stated in OEIS, we rather don't expect any. This is an interesting identity with binomial cubes. Thanks for sharing it. You might be interested in the binomial identities provided at H.W. Goulds [homepage](https://www.math.wvu.edu/~gould/).

Comment: @DragunityMAX: Good observation. The series transformations I've done use precisely this symmetry.